# How easy is it to get in and out of Russia by illegally crossing its border?

Tags: russia, borders, estonia, latvia

I'm unsure whether my question is on-topic here, but it's about travel and border crossing, so I've decided to try.

I'm writing an article about Russian borders, focusing on illegal crossings in both directions. The aim of the article is not to give specific hints to potential illegal border crossers, but to give an objective picture of how well Russia's vast land borders are guarded by Russian border guards and their counterparts on the other side of the border and what are the implications for illegal migration, smuggling, drug trafficking, etc. As a student learning the Russian language, I've been able to find and read various Russian posts and articles about the matter, but almost all information I found dates back to a decade ago or so, so I'm unsure about the current situation. But back then, there were many "holes" in the Russian border. In particular, a large part of the Russian border with Latvia, an EU member, goes through wild swampy forests and was barely marked, let alone guarded, back then. A more or less recent [article](https://rus.postimees.ee/5913254/rossiysko-estonskaya-granica-po-puti-slepney-nelegalov-i-kontrabandy) shows a part of the Russian border with another EU member, Estonia:

[image]

The border control officer interviewed in that article says that a very large part of the Russian-Estonian border is like that, and compares that forest to a jungle. The article makes it very clear that illegal crossings do occur, although some border crossers get caught.

My question: How easy is it to illegally cross the Russian border nowadays? Am I right in understanding that you still can easily cross the Russian border illegally in any direction if you do your homework, take a compass, and avoid silly mistakes like using electronic devices in the border region?

I emphasize that I'm not looking for border-crossing advice and merely want to read the information that sheds light on the overall picture and might help me write my article - e.g., statistics, personal accounts written by refugees, etc. My impression is that there's a big problem that is largely ignored and swept under the rug, and I'd like to know whether my impression is correct and how I can back it up with facts in my article.

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't make sense to me... I mean at least in its current form, the first impression from your question is that Russia probably has or had some immigration problems along with its EU borders, which doesn't make sense cause who wants to illegally migrate to Russia from Estonia or Latvia (both of these countries are in the Schengen area)? In my opinion, Estonian and Latvian should be concerned that some illegal migration might happen from Russia to the EU cause as you may know Russian citizens need visas to enter the Schengen area.

Comment: This question might make sense for Russia's border with some of her East Asian neighbors probably like Kazakhstan that there is more motivation for people to cross the border into Russia, but not for Russia-EU borders. One of the answers here tries to give an example of Russia-Norway border... who wants to cross the Russian border illegally from Norway?! I don't say it's zero but probably it's so close to zero that there might not be illegal immigration from Norway to Russia...

Comment: Are you considering the people going into Russia or the people leaving Russia, or both?

Comment: @Willeke : Both! I'm writing a really detailed analytical article about how well the Russian border is protected by the Russian border guards and the border guards of the Russian neighbours, covering both scenarios - people leaving Russia and people entering Russia. If the Russian border is easy to cross, then, regardless of the direction we consider, there are really multiple implications of that (migration, drugs,  smuggling, escapes from justice, agent missions, etc.), and I'm going to analyze them in my article.

Comment: @Willeke : The starting point of my analysis, and perhaps the most difficult part of it, is about how easy or difficult it actually is to illegally cross the Russian land border and the adjacent border region, in both directions. My question here on Travel SE specifically focuses on that aspect.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer : You have a point, so perhaps I need to clarify that the idea of my article is to analyze how well the Russian border is guarded and consider all implications of that. Migration is only one of the implications of poor protection of a border. There are drugs, smuggling, agent missions, escapes from justice, etc. I guess you aren't really suggesting that Russia shouldn't protect its borders from possible penetration from the EU countries.

Comment: So your question is like if we should ask Mexico to protect its border with the US to prevent the illegal crossing of the US citizen into the Mexico... The answer is mmmmm yes probably but the proportionality of who should keep its border more secure is higher on the US side in my opinion... This proportionality is much higher for Russia-EU case that I would say: No there is almost no illegal immigration from EU to Russia but always you have crazy people that even might cross North Korea - South Korea border to go to North Korea... So it’s just all about statistics but obviously that’s low...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer : And if it's really easy to get to Russia from the EU by illegally crossing the Russian land border, that has serious implications even if there's no substantial flow of migrants from the EU to Russia. I've just updated my question to better reflect my motivation and what I'm asking for.

Comment: Personally, I think I'd be less concerned about the land borders with Estonia (~80 miles) and Latvia (~110 miles) and more concerned with the one with Kazakhstan, Mongolia, and China (almost 6,000 miles.)

Comment: When I visited Nida, Lithuania, in 2008, a local guide warned tourists about hiking in the dunes, as the border is/was not well marked everywhere. She mentioned that some people had unwittingly crossed the border and been detained by Russian authorities for illegal entry. Note that this was the first summer under the Schengen agreement (which Lithuania signed in 2003 and implemented in December 2007), and the incidents may have been earlier. Though I suppose Lithuania would have had to tighten border security in order to join Schengen, that is, prior to its accession.

Comment: The Russian land border is huge, so there are likely huge chunks of unpopulated wilderness that are barely guarded if at all. Not that anyone would choose them to smuggle anything.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

My answer might have fit better as a comment, but is too long, so please bear with me here.

'How easy' is of course difficult to quantify, but it is in most areas not as easy as it might seem. You are completely right that when looking at the Russian border from many European neighbours, it almost looks like an open invite. Contrary to many other, even less 'intimidating' borders, there are absolutely no physical obstacles, not even a fence at the border and you are on the foreign side freely able to move directly up to the border itself.

Here is a picture I took at the Norwegian-Russian border a few years ago:

[image: Norwegian and Russian border markers]

The Norwegian (black/yellow) and Russian (red/green) border markers are standing only some 4-5 meters apart and the actual border line runs exactly in the middle between the two posts. Coming from the Norwegian side, you are allowed to move freely all the way up to the actual border, even on the few meters of Norwegian soil on the other side of the border post. The area is not very far away from the nearest road, the terrain is relatively easy to hike in and if you are interested in entering Russia illegally, it looks as if you only need to take a few more steps to succeed.

It's not that easy. The Norwegian border patrol was *very* aware of our presence, the border is on the Norwegian side probably under gapless electronic surveillance, but not having anyone else but us to 'take care of', we had several cups of coffee and a long chat with one of the patrols. They told us that even they only very occasionally see Russian patrols on the other side of the border, but the quiet is just a deception. At least here, and from what I can find on the internet this applies to the entire Russian border, the 'real' border security is not exerted directly at the border, but up to several 10s of kilometres inside the country. Both access and allowed activities are severly restricted in the Russian border zone, and even you could easily enter Russia here, you would have a hard time getting out of, or even through the border zone without being intercepted.

If we for example take a look at Google Streetview, when approaching Norway by road from the Russian side, [you enter the border zone](https://www.google.de/maps/@69.3815675,30.1129236,3a,48.7y,304.65h,83.08t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sI-sEs-mhqmi51uRD1_arVw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) (blue sign on the right side of the road) already 35 km before the border crossing. Passing this point is only allowed with a permit or if you are on your way to the border crossing. The Streetview imagery is a bit older here, so you can see that the Google car stopped taking photos at this point and didn't proceed into the border zone. Until a few years ago, photography was strictly prohibited in the border zone, but is AFAIK now allowed. You will find this regime all along the Russian border, e.g. [also here](https://www.google.de/maps/@57.6793476,27.576351,3a,75y,253.61h,90.64t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sDCAHsJBGtPtICcRx_sO6DA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) when you approach the Estonian border from the Russian side, this time about 12 km from the border.

If you look at the aerial or satelite photography of the area on Google Maps, Bing or Norgeskart you can in several areas make out long, straight clearings in the forest along the border a bit into Russia. The clearings seem too narrow for a road, but I would not be surprised if what we see are fences.

There is not really much secrecy about this border zone, one can easily find a lot of documentation and information online, but perhaps not so much in English. The [Russian Wikipedia page](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) is quite extensive and the online translation services are good enough to give an understandable version in English. As you can read in this article, the practical implementation of the border zone and the level of surveillance differs a lot from region to region. The Russian border does indeed run through many areas, though most in the Asian part, which are so remote, that it for most practical purposes is impossible to get there and cross.

Comment: "...the 'real' border security is not exerted directly at the border, but up to several 10s of kilometres inside the country" - Reminded me of how in the US the Border Patrol has checkpoints [located 25 and 75 miles (40/121 km) of the US Mexico border.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Border_Patrol_interior_checkpoints) (In addition to at the border itself, obviously).

Comment: As you said there are lots of border patrols in the Norwegian side but nothing in the Russian side, which makes sense cause who wants to illegally migrate to Russia from Norway...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Being one of the easiest accesssible borders between NATO and the Warsaw Pact, there was allegedly quite a lot of illegal traffic across the Norwegian-Russian border in both directions during the cold war. US intelligence still operate in border proximity on the Norwegian side (more or less obviously) and there are still extensive activity on all the military bases just across the border on the Russian side. I would not rule out that there are people there, who would gain from crossing illegally into Russia.

Comment: @BruceWayne I believe that US Immigration can question anyone without any reason within 100 miles/163 km of a border.  Where I live is just outside of that zone.

Comment: @BruceWayne They do, but the important difference is that you don't need a permit or reason to go close to the Mexican border from the US side (in Big Bend National Park or Big Bend Ranch State Park, you can walk all the way up to the border and nobody will question what you are doing there).

Comment: Thanks a lot, and your answer is corroborated by a personal account I read in Russian some time ago. The author claims to be a Russian LGBT refugee who managed to flee Russia by illegally crossing the Russian-Estonian border a decade ago. She says the main difficulty wasn't to cross the border itself, but to get through the border zone on the Russian side. She says that she did it overnight and that her biggest fear was when she was in the wild forest in the Russian border zone and heard a dog barking some kilometers away. The dog must have been of Russian border guards.

Comment: She says she was terrified and didn't move for quite a long while before continuing approaching the border. Anyway, for what it is worth, her story shows that it is, or at least was, quite possible to get through the Russian border zone. Interestingly, she says that one of the keys to success is to take glasses to protect the eyes from small branches in the darkness of the wild forest. Technical details like that made her account look pretty credible.

Comment: @Mitsuko Good boots, that protect the ankels, would also be important when moving through any wild forest due to the irregular ground that one could encounter at any time.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo There was a lot of smuggling between Russia and the Nordic countries during the cold war. People would exchange western goods (to supply the black market) for cheap fuel or alcohol. That was probably the main reason you'd get illegal traffic *into* Russia.

Comment: This reminds me of the German strategy in the Western Front of WWI.  They sought to utilize an "elastic" defense, where their very front lines were actually not super strong, but the true weight of their defense was kept a little further back.  As soon as the Allied Powers would attack, they may overrun the first few trenches or something, but the Germans would respond by quickly deploying a much more focused defense from just slightly behind the initial front lines.  In this way, they were able to very flexibly and rapidly refocus their defenses wherever they needed them most. ...

Comment: ... In the end, the Germans would often repel Allied attackers and recapture most, if not all of the lost ground.  Ultimately this was far more costly for the Allied Powers (who would still have to weather a lot of attrition while getting their first few gains) than it was for the Germans, and it turned out to be a very solid strategy.  What this answer is mentioning is a lot of the same idea.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same for Kaliningrad.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

> How likely is it that someone, who has illegaly entered Russia, be caught while remaining there?

That question is easier to answer, assuming you don't speak Russian fluently **and** don't have a Russian internal passport **and** have not used **any** form of public transport between the border region and the first major city (where irregular checks are made).

Very high, since you will probably be found out once you attempt to stay somewhere overnight and cannot supply the needed immigration card togeather with a stamped visa in your passport.

---

> **[Registration in Russia: What it is and how it is done](https://russiau.com/registration-visa-russia/)**
> **Who must be registered?**
> Registration must be done by the host:
>
> - **Hotel**. If you stay in a hotel, then the hotel management is responsible for the registration upon your check-in.
> - **Apartment**. The host of the apartment must make the registration, be it an individual or a company that manages the apartment.
> - **Private homes**. If you are staying in a private home of a friend or relative, then your friend or family must make your registration at their home address.
>
> ...
> **Registration procedure in Russia**
> ...
> For the registration, the hotel will request at your arrival:
>
> - **Your passport**, from which they will make a photocopy of all pages (including the page where your photo and personal data are and the page that has your visa stamped).
> - **Your immigration card**, from which the hotel will make a photocopy.
>
> With this documentation, the hotel will fill out a special foreign citizen arrival notification form.
> [image]
>
> The hotel administration will also be in charge of the registration process, by filling up the form and presenting it along with the rest of documentation before the Russian immigration authorities. You will be registered in 1-2 business days.
>
> The main part of the form is the one sent to the authorities, while the bottom part (from the dotted line), or a copy, is the one that the hotel can give you as proof and in which the address and the registration deadline is indicated. Once you leave, the hotel will also inform the authorities.

---

**Sources**

- [Registration in Russia: What it is and how it is done](https://russiau.com/registration-visa-russia/)

Comment: There are of course many ways to stay in Russia without being registered. There are an estimated 7 million foreigners living and working illegaly in Russia, so as long as you have been able to enter, it does not seem very difficult to stay under the radar without being caught.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo With specialized knowledge on how things work in Russia and good contacts, maybe. Most of the illegals you have meantioned are probably from former Soviet republics, so have a general idea how things work and in many ways are tolerated as a cheap workforce. Otherwise the degree of difficulty is probably one of the highest in Europe.

Comment: One could get a visa, enter Russia legally, and then cross out of Russia (and back in) illegally. Not sure if that counts as "very difficult".

Comment: @MarkJohnson the stuff about the migration card is true in theory, but in my experience the reality is very different. Maybe major hotel chains are diligent about it but I’ve visited various parts of Russia staying at AirBnBs and family-run hotels, not one of them has wanted to do the registration.

Comment: @ChrisH Maybe, but it would be unwise to assume that is the norm. See the accepted answer as to what can happen if things aren't done correctly. [russia - What to do if I overstayed my e-visa for Saint Petersburg/Leningrad Oblast](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/152419/95267)

Comment: @MarkJohnson I’m certainly not suggesting anybody should go ahead and do this, I just don’t think the chance of being caught can be declared “very high” on the basis of the migration card

Comment: @ChrisH I didn't suggest you did. I think that the lack of the immigration card and stamped visa, preventing a proper registration during the stay, that any simple check within the country makes the possibility of being found out very high. Such system have been designed for a reason, flauting them could have serious consequences.

Comment: Thanks, you have a point, and avoiding getting caught in Russia is a whole separate issue. Yet, for certain categories of illegal border crossers it shouldn't be a real problem. For instance, if you merely want to smuggle something to Russia and go back on the following day, or if you want to get something in Russia and smuggle it to the EU, the risk of getting caught inside Russia isn't the main concern, especially if you have connections there. Or, if you are a migrant and have connections in your ethnic group living in Russia, they can help you with accommodation and transportation.

Comment: Furthermore, if you speak Russian and have enough cash, you can easily rent a short-term accommodation offered by a private person. The key word for search is посуточная аренда (literally "lease on the day-by-day basis"). If you take some basic precautions, pay upfront in cash, and don't cause trouble, you can be sure you won't be reported by your landlord to the authorities in any way, especially since Russian landlords cheat on their taxes and are thus themselves interested to hide everything from the authorities.

Comment: Besides, you don't need any documents to buy tickets for local trains (электрички, as opposed to intercity trains), and you can use local trains to travel across the entire country if you plan your connections.

Comment: Russian officials explicitly say that there are about 2 million illegal immigrants in Russia: https://rg.ru/2018/12/21/v-mvd-nazvali-chislo-nelegalnyh-migrantov-v-rossii.html  How do they manage to live in Russia if it's very hard not to get caught?

Comment: The only real risk seems to be irregular checks by police. That is, a policeman can stop you on a street out of the blue and ask you to show your documents. That's pretty unusual nowadays, but might happen if a policeman sees something weird in your appearance or behavior. You can't completely eliminate that risk, but you can pretty much minimize it. Just look good in terms of clothes and overall appearance, avoid crowded places patroled by police, be confident, avoid doing weird things on public, etc.

Comment: Even if a policeman stops you, there are some options - you can tell a plausible story and say you don't have your documents with you, and there are also ways to safely offer a bribe. You might be surprised by this, but many Russian policemen will prefer to accept a modest bribe rather than to take the hassle of sending yet another illegal immigrant back to his home country.

Comment: Competent undocumented migrants in Russia are unlikely to go to the front desk of a Central Moscow hotel and ask for a room there. Undocumented migrants in western Europe or North America don't do that either. And my experience as a tourist is different from ChrisH's; even a tiny and very cheap hotel remote in the Komi Republic insisted on my migration card.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit old, but according to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolia%E2%80%93Russia_border)

> According to an article published in 2005, the main problems at the Russian-Mongolian border, specifically in its Republic of Tuva section, were cross-border livestock theft (in both directions) and smuggling of meat.[5]

If true, this would imply that the border is not hard to cross at all as long as you can blend in well with the locals.

Of course it is somewhat convenient for the police to blame people outside their jurisdiction for cattle theft, so the real scale of cross-border cattle thievery might be somewhat smaller.

Comment: That's also a particularly remote and unpopulated area, even by Russian standards.

Comment: @gerrit: AFAIK people who cross borders illegally often prefer borders that are remote and unpopulated. E.g. between Mexico and the US or the multiple land borders on the way from various Middle Eastern countries to Europe